# Communication between two different network id

Tags: static-ip

How can two hosts with different network-id communicate with each other?

10.17.101.16 /24 needs to communicate with 10.17.102.16 /24

I was able to make communication by changing them to same network-id by changing subnet mask. But is it the only way to make communication possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're on the same segment then changing the subnet will work but it brings the question of whether that segment was subnetted correctly in the first place.

If they're on different segments then you needs something like a router or layer-3-switch to perform routing.

Comment: If the case is like two nodes are connected to two different switch and the switches are interconnected, will it be on same segment?

Comment: If there's nothing in between and they're 'dumb' switches then yes.

Comment: Ok. can u plse elaborate the 'segment was subnetted properly' part...

Comment: well there are reasons why one segment might be subnetted (i.e. 10.17.101.x and 10.17.102.x) but they're usually pretty advanced cases. Usually you'd only have one subnet per segment for regular basic networks.

Answer (score 2):

Either the communication needs to be in the same subnet or you need to pass communication through a router.

You can make the subnet bigger if 255 addresses is not enough for you, ie /23 or /22.

Otherwise you need a box that has an interface on both subnets and is configured to route traffic between the two.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router

Comment: Ok. I better go off with making my subnet bigger as I am planning not to use routers. Thanks for the reply